# How to append json array using jq+shell in a loop?

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I can create a json object with an array using jq like this

`echo '{"input":{"names":[]}}' |  jq --arg val "alice" '.input.names[0] += $val'| jq --arg val "bob" '.input.names[1] += $val'`

which gives

```
{
  "input": {
    "names": [
      "alice",
      "bob"
    ]
  }
}
```

Now I want to recreate this in a shell script where "names" come from a shell array

```
#!/bin/sh

names=( alice bob )
                 
ITER=0
for i in "${names[@]}"
do                  
    echo '{"input":{"names":[]}}' |  jq --arg val "$i" '.input.names[$ITER] += $val'
    echo ${I} ${ITER}                                                               
    ITER=$(expr $ITER + 1)                                                          
done
```

but I run into

```
jq: error: $ITER is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.input.names[$ITER] += $val             
jq: 1 compile error
0
jq: error: $ITER is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.input.names[$ITER] += $val             
jq: 1 compile error
1
```

Comment: Either assign (`=`, not `+=`) to an array index `jq --arg val "alice" '.input.names[0] = $val'`, or append (`+=`) to an array using no index and the array brackets on the RHS: `jq --arg val "alice" '.input.names += [$val]'`.

Comment: i tried ```echo '{"input":{"names":[]}}' |  jq --arg val "$i" '.input.names += [$val]'``` but it just creates two different objects

Comment: Because you don't capture the output of an iteration step, so you lose the output from one call and start all over again in the next. I have added a `bash` solution implementing your `for` loop while capturing the outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get rid of the shell loop and use one `jq` call:

```sh
names=( alice bob )
jq -n --arg names "${names[*]}" '{"input": {"names": ($names / " ") } }'
```

or

```sh
names=( alice bob )
printf '%s\0' "${names[@]}" |
jq -sR '(. / "\u0000") as $names | { "input": { "names": $names } }'
```

Comment: If I replace `\0` in the `printf` variant with `|` (and of course `\u0000` too) then the array is `["alice","bob",""]`. So why is this not the case with `\0`?

Comment: I don't know the reason. It might be a long standing bug that `\u0000` is treated this way, it's convenient though

Answer (score 2):

You don't capture the output of an iteration step, so you lose the output from the `jq` call and start all over again in the next iteration step.

Here's a `bash` solution which captures the output using `$(...)` and provides it for the next using `<<<`. (Note that there are better ways to solve this problem, e.g. without looping but by proving `jq` all elements to be added at once.)

```sh
json='{"input":{"names":[]}}'

for i in alice bob
do json="$(jq --arg val "$i" '.input.names += [$val]' <<< "$json")"
done

echo "$json"
```

```json
{
  "input": {
    "names": [
      "alice",
      "bob"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: yep...that worked also... thanks